# Hosting images from unsecured servers (travelnow.com)

Tags: language-agnostic

My application needs to serve images hosted in travelnow.com (ie. [this image](http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/170000/168400/168336/168336_48_t.jpg)) but the application only allow images hosted on a secured server (ie. https).

1. What are my options?
2. TravelNow's suggestion is as follows. How do I do this?

   > Akamai image servers are not secure. Therefore you are unable to serve any of the image urls with a secure HTTPS URL. If you need to serve an image with HTTPS, you must temporarily save the image to your own secure server. This is suggested only for images to be saved as you use them or need them temporarily on the secure page.
   >
   > The hotel images file available from the Affiliate Center provides up to 1.5 million URLs at any time for all properties storing images in the Akamai system. It is not recommended or advised to store all files in advance on your own system since properties change and update images frequently.
   >
   > Although we are not responsible for the images each property stores on the Akamai system, YOU will be responsible for any customer issues arising from displaying outdated or saved image files on your own pages.

Thanks!
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

- There is a way to "tunnel" the image
  from TravelNow to the client by
  passing through your server. But that
  will add latency.
- You can also download all files from
  TravelNow and put a system in place
  that refresh your images regularly.
  The first download will be rather
  big. But a check to see if an image
  has changed is rather simple and
  fast.

Comment: Thanks, Thierry. Can you point me to some implementation of "tunneling"? 

-Adrian